# Any way to convert old Angband save files to the current version?

Tags: angband

I recently started playing Angband again after running across my old 3.5" floppy disks with my old saved player files on them.   I like the newer Windows version of Angband (3.4.1 I think) but I've found that it won't open my saved games from 2.7.9.  It tells me the file is corrupt.

Is there any way to get the old files to open in the newer versions?  I haven't yet tried downloading all the interim versions to see if I can baby-step it up to the current version.

It sure would be nice to have my 44th level Rogue to play again since I never did get him quite tough enough to win the game.

Comment: Did you try opening the save files with version 2.7.9 to confirm that they still work and are not actually just corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to convert old savefiles to new versions. The general workaround is to download [version 2.7.9](http://rephial.org/release/2.7.9v1) and finish your game with it. An emulator or a virtual machine may help, since a long time has passed.

Every now and then an update breaks savefile compatibility (usually timed along major version changes); the devs normally prefer to spend their time on other features than trying to write savefile version converters.